# Embedding Python in a Visual Studio 2010 C++ Project

Tags: python, c++

I want to embedd Python in a Visual Studio 2010 C++ Project.

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

I have anaconda with python 2.7.8 installed.

I add in the project properties at 
C/C++ > additional include directiries: C:\Anaconda\include
and 
Linker > additional lib directiories: C:\Anaconda\libs

But still i got some errors:

> Fehler    2   error C3861: "Py_Initialize": Bezeichner wurde nicht gefunden.  D:\Eigene Dokumente\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\test\test.cpp  11

in english:
error C3861: "Py_Initialize": Identifier not found.

Why?